# escaping dots in json evaluation in WSO2 Datamapper

Tags: json, wso2

I have a JSON object as payload, which contains a dot (".") in one of the identifier names and I want to map this object to another JSON object using the datamapper mediator.

The problem I am facing is that the JSON evaluation uses the dot notation for nested elements. The field "example":

```
{ "a": { "b": "example"} }
```

is evaluated by asking for a.b

My object however looks like:

```
{ "a": { "b.c": "example"} }
```

I cannot evaluate a.b.c, because it thinks b and c are two seperate nested elements.

Escaping this identifier name in the datamapper.dmc javascript code does not seem to work. No matter what I try ('', "", [''], [""]) I get the error:

```
Error while reading input stream. Script engine unable to execute the script javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:8:43 Expected ident but found [
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exact solution as I did not specifically tried it for Data Mapper, but I had similar problem in WSO2 Property Mediator while parsing incoming JSON to get a value and set it to property. I was able to parse such JSON using following syntax

```
json-eval($.A.['b.c'])
```

Where 'A' is JSON object containing 'b.c' JSON element.

I saw you mentioned that you already tried something similar, but just wanted to give my working example in case it helps.